# JavaScript: Convert string to value of predefined variable

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript object that looks like the following:

```
venue = function(map, dataSet) {
    // set some constants
    this.VENUE_ID = 0;
    this.VENUE_NAME = 1;
    this.VENUE_CITY = 2;

    this.filterBy = function(field, value) {
        ...
        var filterValue = 'parent.VENUE_' + field;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I need the value of `filterValue` to contain the value of the constant on the parent object. Currently I have tried using the method shown above and then referencing the filterValue when trying to access the array item, but this simply returns undefined.

How do I convert the `filterValue` variable into the value of the constant it represents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the variable scope.

```
var filterValue = this['VENUE_' + field];
```

would do.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has no concept of 'parent'. And I think you're confusing scope and context. If that method was written as var filterBy() you'd have to access it in a different 'scope'. But by using 'this' you kept in in the same object as it was written. So everything you wrote is in 'this' context.

Comment: Ah I see! Well thank you, I had no idea. I had been manually setting the parent to 'this' externally to each function up until this point. I think the reason was something to do with using functions as callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var filterValue = this['VENUE_' + field];
```